# Dense Rank con Campo Calculado en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Alguna sugerencia tengo que crear un ranking
La tabla inicia como se muestra
[image: Tengo una tabla así]

Para empezar no puedo usar la función dense_rank ya que mi servidor remoto no lo soporta

```
SELECT fcdb_alineaciones.nombre AS nombre,
COUNT(fcdb_alineaciones.nombre) AS partidosjugados,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY partidosjugados DESC) AS densoranking 
FROM fcdb_alineaciones
WHERE minutosjugados>0
GROUP BY fcdb_alineaciones.nombre
ORDER BY partidosjugados DESC
```

Lo intento de este modo

```
SELECT nombre, conteo,
(SELECT COUNT(*) +1  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(nombre) AS conteo
FROM fcdb_alineaciones
WHERE minutosjugados>0                           
GROUP BY nombre                 
ORDER BY COUNT(nombre) DESC) b
WHERE a.conteo < b.conteo ) AS ranking
FROM (SELECT nombre, COUNT(nombre) AS conteo
FROM fcdb_alineaciones
WHERE minutosjugados>0      
GROUP BY nombre 
ORDER BY COUNT(nombre)DESC) a
ORDER BY conteo DESC, nombre ASC
```

El resultado que deseo obtener es como la imagen, de antemano gracias.

[image: EL resultado que espero encontrar es como la imagen]

Answer (score 0):

Donde dice 'cant' seria la fila que va a sacar el mas alto, result sera donde se motrara el del primero al ultomo

```
SELECT id, name, cant, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY cant DESC) result FROM database LIMIT 10
```